# Swashbuckle: Description not populated for reference objects in requests body reference

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using swashbuckle (version 6.5.0) to generate an open api document (version 3).

I have a POST request that has a [FromBody] parameter. The [FromBody] parameter is an object, that has other objects nested inside of it. I have not found how to have swashbuckle add the description for these objects that are nested within the main request body object. Showing example below for a better explanation.

```
[HttpPost("{Id}")]
public class Task<ActionResult> PostRequest([SwaggerParameter(Description = "Description for Route Parameter.")][FromRoute] int id, [SwaggerRequestBody(Description = "Description for Body Parameter")][FromBody] RequestBodyClass request)
{
   ...
}
```

```
[SwaggerSchema(Description = "Description for class")]
public class RequestBodyClass
{
    [SwaggerSchema(Description = "Name field description")
    public string nameField {get; set;}

    [SwaggerSchema(Description = "Nested object description")
    public OtherClass nestedObjectField {get; set;}
}
```

The generated swagger doc is below, note that the request body referenced object has the nested object inside of it, but the description is not there for it.

```
paths:
  '/{Id}':
    post:
      ...
      requestBody:
        Description: Description for Body Parameter
        content:
          application/json:
            schema: 
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestBodyClass'
      ...
components:
  schemas:
    RequestBodyClass:
      type: object
      properties:
       ** Task:
          --Notice no description in the Task node--
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NestedClass'**
      additionalProperties: false
      description: Description for class
```

I would've expected the the Task property inside the RequestBodyClass schema to have the description "Nested object description" so that I can describe that object in the request body. Is this by design?